# View images and captions

Tags: 18.04, eog, image-viewers

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 (x86_64, kernel `4.15.0-50-generic`). The default image viewer is [EOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_GNOME).

In a directory I stored some images and a text file for each image, with the caption.

1. Is it possible to display **both** the image and the caption with EOG?
2. If not, is there any other image viewer which can do this?

Answer (score 3):

I use Kubuntu 18.04 which has Gwenview as its image viewer. It's available in the repositories but it may pull in quite a few dependencies if you haven't already installed other `qt`-based applications. Run `apt install -s gwenview` to see if you're comfortable installing it.

[image]

Gwenview doesn't display a text file and the corresponding image together but it has a sidebar in which you can enter a description of your image by typing or pasting content in the Description box.

In the following composite,

- the first image has the description area blank
- the second, third, and fourth images have small descriptions.

[image: Gwenview showing descriptions of images]

---

Gwenview uses something called "extended file attributes" to store information you enter in the Descriptions box. I learned that [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/75507-Where-does-Gwenview-save-text-entered-as-a-description?p=427783&viewfull=1#post427783).

If you decide you want to extract all the descriptions, you can. First install *xattr* from the Universe repository.

> Description: tool for manipulating filesystem extended attributes

Then, run

```
xattr -l *.png
```

from the folder containing your images, assuming them to be *.png*.

You'll get a consolidated output like this:

```
01-default.png: user.xdg.comment: This is the default color scheme of the Ranger file manager.  
02-jungle.png: user.xdg.comment: Jungle is another color scheme included when you install Ranger.  
03-snow.png: user.xdg.comment: This is snow, the third color scheme included with Ranger.   
04-solarized.png: user.xdg.comment: This is solarized. This color scheme isn't included with Ranger.
```

I haven't addressed the following issues because I don't understand much about extended file attributes myself:

- where this information is stored
- whether the information can be accessed by other programs
- the maximum length of material you can include in the description

but the following links could be of use:

- [Extended File Attributes Rock!](https://www.linuxtoday.com/blog/extended-file-attributes-rock.html)
- [where are extended attributes stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20618492)
- [Differences between purposes of inode, fork and extended file attribute?](https://superuser.com/q/296711)
- [How to View & Remove Extended Attributes from a File on Mac OS](http://osxdaily.com/2018/05/03/view-remove-extended-attributes-file-mac/)